# Flutter Bend Widget from Bottom

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-custompainter

I have a very specific use case and I can't find a way to achieve that in Flutter.

Let's say we have a widget (could be image, container, svg etc.) like this:

[image]

Now I want to bend the widget with bottom as the changing axis like this:

[image]

And like this:

[image]

- But I can't use custom paint to draw the widget since I want it to be
  an svg image which I cannot accurately draw in custom paint,
- Using
  Clip path will crop the widget,

**Do you guys have any ideas on how to achieve this in Flutter?**

Comment: It can be done using custom paint and beizer curves. The green circle will be draggable and the curve will generate automatically. Not sure if it can be achieved without this option. Maybe try Matrix 4

Comment: How will curve generate automatically?

Comment: With beizer curves it should create curves automatically between 2 vectors